# Not getting the SD Card related intents to my broadcast receiver

Tags: android, sd-card

I am trying to register a receiver for the removal of the sdcard, but my receiver is not getting called on removal of the sd card pasting my code here. I am registering the receiver in the oncreate() and unregistering in the ondestroy function. Please let me know if i am doing any mistake.

```
void registerSDCardStateChangeListener() {
    final String MEDIA_REMOVED = "android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED";
    final String MEDIA_UNMOUNTED = "android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED";
    final String MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL = "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL";
    //      final String MEDIA_EJECT = "android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT";
    final String MEDIA_EJECT = "android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED";

    mSDCardStateChangeListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @
        Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(MEDIA_REMOVED) || action.equalsIgnoreCase(MEDIA_UNMOUNTED) || action.equalsIgnoreCase(MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL) || action.equalsIgnoreCase(MEDIA_EJECT)) {
                if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                    stopPlayBack();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(MEDIA_REMOVED);
    filter.addAction(MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
    filter.addAction(MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL);
    filter.addAction(MEDIA_EJECT);
    registerReceiver(mSDCardStateChangeListener, filter);
}
```

Please let me know if anything is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try adding this to your intent-filter

```
filter.addDataScheme("file");
```

It appears the actions you are trying to catch send the path as the data field of the intent. If that is the case, then your intent filter must have the matching scheme.

Finally, and this is just a suggestion, but I would recommend you use the constants in the Intent class instead of typing out your actions manually. IE, use Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED instead of you using the string directly.

Comment: @Justin Breitfeller +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Justin Breitfeller's answer worked for me, but as an alternate technique, you can also do this entirely in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"
  android:name="SDCardStateChangeListener">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then make the receiver a proper class:

```
public class OnMediaMountedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT)) {
            if(mMediaPlayer != null) {
                stopPlayBack();
            }
        }               
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solutions while app is running and user unmount/removed sdcard.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onStart();

    IntentFilter ejectFilter = new ntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    ejectFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
    ejectFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT);
    ejectFilter.addDataScheme("file");
    registerReceiver(ejectReceiver, ejectFilter);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(ejectReceiver);
}
```

In class, define method like below,

```
BroadcastReceiver ejectReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{               
      @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)) 
        {
            Log.e("msg","Media Unmounted");

            //do something on unmounted sdcard from device
        }
    }
};
```

Hope it will be helpful.