# Android SDCard I/O Managing Mount and Unmount

Tags: android, sqlite, io, corruption

I know there are various version of this question asked, but I was having trouble getting a clear answer on what the best approach is for my problem.

What I am doing is I am creating  a SQLite database on the SD card. I want to be able to query from it and write to it.

The question I have is what is the best way to manage when the SD card is unmounted. I am totally fine with my application closing like the stock MP3 player does. However, I want to make sure any write action to the db do not get partially done.

One thought I had is the use beginTransaction, mark it as successful, and then call end transaction. The question I have is what happens if end of transaction does not get called. Can that potentially lead to data corruption? Also, I need a little help understanding what to listen to or hook into to get notification of the sd card being unmounted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the great thing about transactions in databases - you almost never need to worry:

> "All changes within a single transaction in SQLite either occur
>   completely or not at all, even if the act of writing the change out to
>   the disk is interrupted by
>
> a program crash, an operating system crash, or a power failure."

Taken from http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html

The disk being removed on which the database resides should (in the worst case) behave like a power failure while writing the data to the disk. The database will discard that data on next startup.

Thus, as soon as your transaction is committed [using commit or end transaction](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) and the method call executing your statement returns all data has been stored. Otherwise NO data from your transaction will have been stored - both cases leave you in a consistent state.

Beware of the only catch: You will need to make sure that all statements you need to execute together (i.e. atomically) must be within one transaction!

Comment: Patrick, do you have any insight on how to close the app once the sd card is unmounted?

Comment: Hi Jib. Partly yes. If your app is installed on the external storage, it will be closed by the Android system when the storage is unmounted [ref](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html). If only your database is installed on the external storage, then you might be interested in registering a broadcast receiver for ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT intent, see [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293886/not-getting-the-sd-card-related-intents-to-my-broadcast-receiver).