# Dynamically created receiver for Media Mounted/Removed events on Android

Tags: android, subclass, media, android-broadcastreceiver

While the activity is visible, I would like for it to be notified when media is mounted or removed from the device. Unfortunately, I have not been able to get these notifications. The only one I can get is `foo!` which I created as a simple test.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(ActivityFamily.class.getName(), intent.getAction());
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("foo!");
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    // just added this as a test for "foo!" action
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 2000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent().setAction("foo!"), 0));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  }
}
```

Why is `onReceive` not being called when I remove media from the device?

I even tried creating a brand new `MyReceiver.java` and defining it in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but that didn't work either.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I found the answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293886/not-getting-the-sd-card-related-intents-to-my-broadcast-receiver) I needed to add the `file:` scheme to the intent filter.

Before using `registerReceiver` add `filter.addDataScheme("file");`

For static broadcast receivers registered in the manifest, add `<data android:scheme="file" />` within the `<intent-filter>`.